# VPN Issue - Unable to reach Servers when connected to VPN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vpn, routing

I have a user who's laptop every time he connected to the VPN the internet on his laptop would completely cut out. To get round this issue I changed the config of the VPN connection to not use the default gateway on remote network by un-ticking the box in Advanced TP/IP Settings.

This then solved the issue of the internet connection on the users laptop but it now stops them from accessing any of the servers on the network. It does not pick up a default gateway although should this really matter for trying to reach servers that are on the network?

I'm looking for a bit of advice on the effect of not having the default gateway being picked up.

When connected to the original VPN which has the check box ticked for Use default gateway on remote network, it would pick up the default gateway is 0.0.0.0 and be able to ping all of our servers with no issues. When un-ticking that option the default gateway is blank and nothing can be reached on the network.

From what I can see I do not think this is an issue with the VPN set up on our network as I can access it from another laptop using the original Config of having the use default Gateway on Remote Network ticked with not issues.

If there is another way to get round the internet completely dropping on the users laptop when Connected to the VPN then that would work.

Any advice or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like the users machine is the culprit. However you can look at routes to see what is going on. Unsure how much you know about routes so a quick lessons Windows has a routes table which says anything on IP 10.x.x.x go to interface IP x.x.x.x and you'll find it.. If one route has a lower metric than another then it will take preference. You can get the windows route table by CMD route print command. Taking this in to account it would interesting to see what the results from this are before and after the VPN is connected.

Comment: The results of the route print command are the same before and after the VPN is connected. It looks like the users laptop that is causing the issues but for the life of me can't figure out why the internet drops every time the VPN is connected. Could it be the NIC playing up?

Comment: I would have thought you would have other issues if it was the NIC.. can you add the route print to the question maybe masking anything important (like external IP's) internal are standard so no need to hide...

Comment: Appologies the routes are different, I will try and add this to the question now.

Comment: Just for clarification, are these routes picked up by the network or are they stored locally?

Comment: They are 'picked up' in a very loose term, they work on an algorithm to build its list.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what brand of VPN you're using, but here's a bit of background.

Typically, when a VPN connection is established, the device "ignores" the default route and sends traffic across the VPN tunnel to the other side.  BUT, the computer still needs a default route so that the VPN connection can be established in the first place.

If you want to send "private" traffic across the VPN connection, but send everything else, such as Internet traffic, to the default gateway, this is a scenario known as "Split-Tunneling."

Some VPN clients have a checkbox to allow split-tunneling.  Using split-tunneling requires some sort of rule or policy to identify the traffic that does need to go across the VPN.

I can help more if I could know what flavor of VPN is being used.

Comment: The user is just using the built in Windows VPN Client. I am hesitant to change the setup of the VPN as I have tested it using my laptop and I can get access no problem and have no issues reaching any of our servers. I think this is more of an issue with the users laptop but I am a bit stumped as to why this is happening.